# Strange errors in Python tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a quiz game in Python tkinter. The code runs as expected until the program finishes asking all the questions in the quiz. When it gets to that part, it's supposed to display a pie chart that presents the correct and wrong answers. It does display the pie chart, but strange errors get printed to the console. These are the errors:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\PycharmProjects\quiz\main.py", line 82, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: run2.check_if_correct(correct_answers, counter_int, 3))
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\PycharmProjects\quiz\main.py", line 37, in check_if_correct
    run3.questions()
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\PycharmProjects\quiz\main.py", line 68, in questions
    question_num.configure(text="Question #%d" % (self.counter + 1))
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!label3"
```

Can someone explain to me what needs to be fixed?
My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from itertools import count

window = Tk()
correct_answers = 0
window.title("Python Quiz")
width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
height = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))


class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, kwargs, activebackground="lightblue", font=20)


class App:
    counter = count(0)
    def __init__(self, button1 = MyButton(window), button2 = MyButton(window),
                 button3 = MyButton(window), button4 = MyButton(window)):
            self.button1 = button1
            self.button2 = button2
            self.button3 = button3
            self.button4 = button4

    @staticmethod
    def check_if_correct(correct, counter, num):
        global correct_answers
        if correct[counter] == num:
            messagebox.showinfo("Python Quiz", "Correct!")
            correct_answers += 1
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Python Quiz", "Incorrect!")

        run3 = App()
        run3.questions()

    def questions(self):
        self.counter = next(self.counter)
        questions_list = ["What is the data type of the following object?: 3.5",
                          "What is a correct syntax to output \"Hello World\" in Python?",
                          "How do you insert COMMENTS in Python code?",
                          "Which one is NOT a legal variable name?",
                          "How do you create a variable with the NUMERIC value 5?",
                          "What is the output of the following code?",
                          "What is the output of the following code?",
                          "What is the output of the following code?",
                          "What is the output of the following code?"]

        answers = [["float", "int", "str", "bool"],
                   ["printf(\"Hello World\")", "print(Hello World)", "print(\"Hello World\")", "print\"(Hello)\""],
                   ["\\ COMMENT", "// COMMENT", "/* COMMENT */", "# COMMENT"],
                   ["MyVar", "my-var", "_myVar", "my_var"],
                   ["x == 5", "x = int(5)", "x = 5", "Options 2 and 3 are both correct"],
                   [955, 3692, -1, 105],
                   ["The sum is 6", "The sum is 4", "The sum is 5", "The sum is 22"],
                   ["True", "yes", "False", "no"],
                   ["100 97 180 99 101", "100 180 101", "97 99", "None of\nthe above"]]

        correct_answers = [0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0]
        counter_int = self.counter
        run2 = App()

        if counter_int >= 9:
            run2.win()

        question_num.configure(text="Question #%d" % (self.counter + 1))
        question_num.place(x=380, y=20)
        question_label.configure(text=questions_list[self.counter])
        question_label.place(x=130, y=100)
        self.button1.configure(text=answers[self.counter][0],
                               command=lambda: run2.check_if_correct(correct_answers, counter_int, 0))
        self.button1.place(x=200, y=400)
        self.button2.configure(text=answers[self.counter][1],
                               command=lambda: run2.check_if_correct(correct_answers, counter_int, 1))
        self.button2.place(x=400, y=400)
        self.button3.configure(text=answers[self.counter][2],
                               command=lambda: run2.check_if_correct(correct_answers, counter_int, 2))
        self.button3.place(x=600, y=400)
        self.button4.configure(text=answers[self.counter][3],
                               command=lambda: run2.check_if_correct(correct_answers, counter_int, 3))
        self.button4.place(x=800, y=400)

        if self.counter >= 5:
            question_read = open("question%d.txt" % (self.counter + 1), "r")

            st = ""
            for d in question_read.readlines():
                for a in d:
                    if a not in "{}":
                        st += a

            code_label.configure(text=st)
            question_read.close()
            code_label.place(x=230, y=170)

        return correct_answers[self.counter]

    def win(self):
        destroy_list2 = [code_label, question_num, question_label,
                         self.button1, self.button2, self.button3, self.button4]

        for j in destroy_list2:
            j.destroy()

        data = [["a", (correct_answers / 9), "lime"], ["b", 1 - (correct_answers / 9), "red"]]
        canvas = Canvas(window, height=500, width=500)
        canvas.pack()

        p = 0
        for c in data:
            angle = c[1] * 360
            canvas.create_arc(400, 400, 100, 100, start=p, extent=angle, fill=c[2])
            p += angle


def start_command():
    destroy_list = [welcome, quit_button, start_button]

    for i in destroy_list:
        i.destroy()

    run = App()
    run.questions()


welcome = Label(window, text="Welcome the Python Quiz!", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 50))
welcome.place(x=230, y=20)

start_button = Button(window, text="START", bg="lime", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 50), width=7,
                              command=lambda: start_command())
start_button.place(x=470, y=220)

quit_button = Button(window, text="QUIT", bg="red", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 50), width=7,
                             command=lambda: quit())
quit_button.place(x=470, y=370)
question_label = Label(window, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30), text="")
question_num = Label(window, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 30), text="")
code_label = Label(window, font=20)


window.mainloop()
```

The content of the text files used in the program:
question6.txt:

```
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
  if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
    print(num1)
  elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
    print(num2)
  else:
    print(num3)

max_num(3692,955,105)
```

question7.txt:

```
def count_digit (num):
    sum= 0
    while num>=1:
         sum=sum+num%10
         num=num//10
    print("The sum is: " + str(sum))

count_digit(63625)
```

question8.txt:

```
def is_there_char(str):
    if str.find("!") == -1:
        print("no")
    else:
        print("yes")

is_there_char("pink")
```

question9.txt:

```
my_dict = {
  "32233344": 100,
  "08098509": 97,
  "22222299": 180,
  "23563346" : 99,
  "22224444" : 101
}
for key in my_dict:
    if my_dict [key] >90:
        print(my_dict[key])
```

Comment: In your `win` function you call `.destroy()` on `question_num`. Once you destroy a label you can no longer access it.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the help!